# Java RMI Method Call Connection Refused with OpenVPN

Tags: java, rmi, openvpn

Grrr, I feel that this should be so obvious yet I can't find the solution.

For testing purposes I have created a simple Client and Server for an RMI application. I can successfully run the client and server over a local network. I can also successfully run the application when connected through a Windows 10 Built-In VPN connection. However, when connected via an OpenVPN connection I receive a `Connection refused to host` exception when calling a method (`String response = lookup.helloTo(txt);` in the Client code) on the remote object returned from the successful call to `lookup = (RMIInterface)Naming.lookup("//192.168.10.14/MyServer");`.

All my Google searches state that the `java.rmi.server.hostname` property must be set which I have done in this case. I am thinking that the issue may be between the VPN client IP address (10.8.0.14) and the server IP address (192.168.10.14). I can ping the server IP address and telnet to port 1099 on the server successfully.

Here is my code. I was hoping if someone could see something that I am missing or doing wrong or if I am on the right track regarding the VPN Client IP <=> Server IP.

**Remote Interface:**

```
package devel;
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface RMIInterface extends Remote {
    public String helloTo(String name) throws RemoteException;
}
```

**Server:**

```
package devel;

import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class ServerOperation extends UnicastRemoteObject implements RMIInterface {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected ServerOperation() throws RemoteException {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public String helloTo(String name) throws RemoteException {
        System.err.println(name + " is trying to contact!");

        return "Server says hello to " + name;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            java.lang.System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", "192.168.10.14");
            java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
            Naming.rebind("//192.168.10.14/MyServer", new ServerOperation());
            System.err.println("Server is ready");
        } catch(Exception exc) {
            System.err.println("Server exception: " + exc.toString());
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Client:**

```
package devel;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ClientOperation {
    private static RMIInterface lookup;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, RemoteException, NotBoundException {
        lookup = (RMIInterface)Naming.lookup("//192.168.10.14/MyServer");
        String txt = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your name?");

        String response = lookup.helloTo(txt);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, response);
    }
}
```

**Exception received:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 192.168.10.14; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.helloTo(Unknown Source)
    at devel.ClientOperation.main(ClientOperation.java:17)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: You need to set it to the public IP address that can be seen from outside, whatever that is.

Comment: Do you mean on the client or the server side, or both? It doesn't make sense to change the server side because that would cause issues with people using it on the local network. I also tried using the internet connection's IP address (or public IP)...no go. And since I am connected to the VPN, I don't believe I should need to use the public IP address.

Comment: It is set at the JVM which exports remote objects, and you need to use an IP address which is reachable by all clients.

Comment: Yep, when the OpenVPN connection is made I can ping the server IP address (192.168.10.14) and telnet to port # 1099 on the server as well. Still no luck calling the method though.

Comment: So set `java.rmi.server.hostname` to 192.168.10.14 at the server JVM. If you need a more public IP address than that you may need to arrange port forwarding.

Comment: Uhhmm?!? I did that from the start. It is basically the first line of code in the 'main' method in the server class as shown in my original post.